# Multiple toggle links

Tags: javascript, html

I'm working with HTML and JavaScript and I need to make two instances of a toggle link.  Here is my code for a single one:

```
<script language="javascript"> 
function toggle() {
    var ele = document.getElementById("toggleText");
    var text = document.getElementById("displayText");
    if(ele.style.display == "block") {
            ele.style.display = "none";
        text.innerHTML = "link1";
    }
    else {
        ele.style.display = "block";
        text.innerHTML = "link1";
    }
} 
</script> 


<body> <a id="displayText" href="javascript:toggle()" style="font-size:160%;">link1</a> 
    <div id="toggleText" style="display: none; font-size:160%;"><p>paragraph1</p></div><br></body>
```

I need the two toggle links to independently show/hide different paragraphs of text when each one is clicked. How can I add a second instance below the first?

Comment: you mean something like this http://jsfiddle.net/bLu5q625/

Comment: @JAG That'll do! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Add an event handler and a data-toggle-id attribute to each link. In your event handler, get the value of the data-toggle-id and use that to find the paragraph that you would like to show. Then use the toggle method of the element's classList to add/remove a class that shows the paragraph.

```js
var links = document.querySelectorAll('[data-toggle-id]');

for (var ix = 0; ix < links.length; ix++) {
  links.item(ix).addEventListener('click', function() {
    document.getElementById(this.dataset.toggleId).classList.toggle('show');
  });
}
```

```css
.toggleText {
    display: none;
}

.show {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/skeleton/2.0.4/skeleton.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <a data-toggle-id="paragraph1">link1</a>
  <div class="toggleText" id="paragraph1">
    <p>paragraph1</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <a data-toggle-id="paragraph2">link2</a>
  <div class="toggleText" id="paragraph2">
    <p>paragraph2</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <a data-toggle-id="paragraph3">link3</a>
  <div class="toggleText" id="paragraph3">
    <p>paragraph3</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you hate for loops, you can use Nick's suggestion and convert the NodeList to and array and use the forEach method:

```
Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('[data-toggle-id]')).forEach(function(element) {
    element.addEventListener('click', function(){
        document.getElementById(this.dataset.toggleId).classList.toggle('show');
    });
});
```

Comment: I've never tried that, but querySelectorAll returns a NodeList and a NodeList doesn't have a forEach method. Maybe some browsers support it?